# Create a sequence of Links

Tags: oracle11g, connect-by

Imagine I have paths made out of one or more segments.
Every path has an **id** and you can check if a segment is from a path using its **id**. Every segment has a **begin** point and an **end** point.

The problem is that the segments are not ordered as begin-end-begin-end:

**Segments Table:**

```
id  | begin |  end  | start_with
123 |  'a'  |  'b'  | 'a'
123 |  'b'  |  'b'  | 'a'
123 |  'd'  |  'b'  | 'a'
123 |  'd'  |  'e'  | 'a'
123 |  'c'  |  'e'  | 'a'
123 |  'f'  |  'c'  | 'a'
456 |  'a'  |  'a'  | 'a'
456 |  'z'  |  'a'  | 'a'
456 |  'z'  |  'e'  | 'a'
789 |  'k'  |  'e'  | 'e'
```

What I really need is to order the segments of each path from where it starts to where it ends, and give it **sequence** numbers, as you can see in the following table:

```
id  | begin |  end  | sequence
123 |  'a'  |  'b'  | 1
123 |  'b'  |  'b'  | 2
123 |  'd'  |  'b'  | 3
123 |  'd'  |  'e'  | 4
123 |  'c'  |  'e'  | 5
123 |  'f'  |  'c'  | 6
456 |  'a'  |  'a'  | 1
456 |  'z'  |  'a'  | 2
456 |  'z'  |  'e'  | 3
789 |  'k'  |  'e'  | 1
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
WITH t as (SELECT id, begin, end, start_with FROM segments)
SELECT distinct t.*,level sequence FROM t
        START WITH BEGIN = start_with OR END = start_with
        CONNECT BY NOCYCLE 
        PRIOR ID = ID
        AND (PRIOR BEGIN = END
          OR PRIOR BEGIN = BEGIN 
          OR PRIOR END = BEGIN 
          OR PRIOR END = END)
```

I believe I'm not so far of the solution, but I'm missing something here, instead of having only the sequence numbers I need, I'm getting multiple repeated sequence numbers, just like it's creating siblings for every single level of the sequence.

Also, I have around 4.5k segments from around 3k paths, and it's giving me millions of records.

Please, any help is more than welcome.

Comment: It's not obvious to me how you get from your data set to your desired result.  For `id` 123, how does it make sense to go from a to b, then b to b, then d to b, then d to e, then c to e, then f to c?

Comment: I don't understand your description. For me a path is a sequence of segments where the end of a segemnts equals the begin of the following segment. But that's apperently not your definition of a path. So what is the meaning of path in your post?

Comment: @miracle173 it doesn't really matter which one is the beginning or the ending point, they are the same, but right now, I only have this segments table, not ordered by begin-end. In other words, the segments are bidirectional and the path will be mounted using those segments. If it's still unclear, imagine a computer network with a lot of computers between Computer A and Computer Z. What I'm trying to achieve is the level of each segment into this route.
Thanks!

Comment: I still don't understand and I don't know much about computer networks. It is completely unclear what a 'path' is in a problem.What is the path with id=123? Can you write down it in some way tha shows it structure? Can you  draw it?